# Why can not I use toString().length() as a hashCode() return?

Tags: java, string, collections, scjp, ocpjp

```
public class Dog
{
    int collarID;
    String name;
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Dog d = new Dog();  
       d.name="hose";  
       System.out.print(d.hashCode());            
    }

    public boolean equals(Object arg0)
    {
        if (arg0 instanceof Dog)
        {
            Dog new_name = (Dog) arg0;
            return collarID==new_name.collarID && new_name.name.equals(name);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        return toString().length();//StackOverflow
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Is there a recurrent call to hashCode() method because of default toString() method?

Comment: @Rohit Jain's answer explains the stack overflow. But I would recommend against generating a string just to get the hash code. In this case, why not just use `collarID ^ String.valueOf(name).hashCode()`?

Comment: It is a question I did wrong in a mock exam

Comment: I see. This must have been a nasty surprise, then. For future reference, it's good rule of thumb to assume that Java tries to make the default implementation say unequal until you say otherwise. This leads to less unexpected behavior. To that end, instances of classes that don't define `toString`, `equals`, `hashCode` will show different string, hashcodes and say they are unequal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you see the source code of `toString` method of `Object` class, it looks like: -

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So, it internally invokes `hashCode()` method. Now, since you have overrided the `hashCode` method, it will invoke the `hashCode` method of your class, which agains invokes `toString` method of `Object` class.

This will certainly result in `StackOverFlowError`

You can rather override the `toString` method in your class, to make it work.

**P.S.: -**

However, your `hashCode` implementation should be designed, considering the attributes you have used in `equals` method, to maintain the `contract` between `hashCode` and `equals` method. Use only those `attributes` in calculating `hashCode` that you have used to compare your `instances` in `equals` method.

See these links for more details on `hashCode` and `equals` method:-

- [`Effective Java - Item # 8 - Obey the general contract when overriding equals`](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/methods-common-to-all-objects/ch03lev1sec1)
- [`Effective Java - Item # 9 - Always override hashCode when you override equals`](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/methods-common-to-all-objects/ch03lev1sec1#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAxMzcxNTAwMjElMkZjaDAzbGV2MXNlYzI=)

Comment: the default impl of toString() should probably use the default hashCode instead (System.identityHashCode())

Comment: @irreputable. Since the current instance inside the `toString` method is of the OP's class, and he has overrided the `hashCode` method, so according to polymorphism, the `hashCode` in OP's class will be invoked.